# C++ multiple inline explicit specializations

Tags: c++, template-specialization, one-definition-rule

The C++ standard specifies that only one explicit specialization of a template can exist in a program ([[temp.spec] paragraph 5 bullet 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#5.2)).

Also, explicit specializations can be declared `inline`.

However, I could not find anything in the standard that explicitly specifies that, for example, an inline explicit specialization of a function template can be defined in multiple translation units.

Is there such wording in the standard?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a defect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I read other answers on stackoverflow which say that an explicit specialization of a function template is actually a normal function (which sounds right), however I do not find that mention in the standard either.

Comment: It doesn't have to be mentioned explicitly. Since it's no longer a template, there's nothing else it can be. It must be normal function (hence, make it `inline` if it's specialized in a header).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Could you tell me where does it say that it is no longer a template? Also, in function overloading there is a difference between normal functions and explicit specializations.

Comment: Again, that doesn't have to be mentioned explicitly. The original template still exists, but the full specialization can't be further specialized or adjusted via template arguments. I.e. it's not a template of anything. It would be different if C++ supported partial specialization of function templates, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok. so it is "implicit" that an explicit specialization of a function template is a normal function, therefore the odr-rules for normal functions apply. Thank you.